# Powershell get folders sizes with sort on remote computer using psexec and oneliner

Tags: powershell, sorting, size, directory, psexec

I need to get folder sizes on remote computer using psexec ( command is limited to 255 characters ).

Main things:

1. psexec [ limit to 255 characters ] - oneliner
2. powershell executed from cmd
3. sort by bytes
4. eliminate values lower than something in MB

I managed to do this this way (without sort/greater than):

```
powershell -exe bypass -c "gci -Force | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name + ': ' + '{0:N2} MB' -f ((gci $_ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue Length -Sum ).Sum / 1MB)}"
```

But I want also to sort by bytes output or/and eliminate folders with size lower than ( or at least starting with 0,xx ).

Thanks for help.

--------- UPDATE ---------

Too bad command ( provided below in answer ) executed remotely gives lots of errors and don't finish well.
I have another command which works on all systems but have no idea how to **sort output by bytes / second column** and **don't exceed 255 characters**.

Here is command [ 234 characters ]:

```
powershell -exe bypass -c "gci -Force | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name + ': ' + '{0:N2} MB' -f ((gci $_ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue Length -Sum ).Sum / 1MB)}"
```

And shorter version [ 173 characters ]:

```
powershell -exe bypass -c "gci -Force | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.Name + ': ' + '{0:N2} MB' -f ((gci $_ -Recurse -EA 0 | Measure-Object -EA 0 Length -Sum ).Sum / 1MB)}"
```

Anyone has idea how to solve this?

Comment: Is there some reason to insist on PSExec rather than doing it over the network directly, possibly using WMI?

Comment: Yes I insist that this is oneliner limited to 255 characters - including powershell -exe bypass -c " "

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally did this, with files number too:

```
powershell -exe bypass -c "gci -Dir | % { $F = gci $_.FullName -Recurse -File ; $Size = '{0:F2}' -f (( $F | Measure -Property Length -Sum).Sum /1MB) ; [PSCustomObject]@{Dir = $_.FullName ; '#' = "$($F.Count)" ; Size = $Size} } | sort {[int]$_.Size} -des"
```

Maybe this will be useful for someone :)

Greetings